# Is it better to group methods together in one method or to have several methods?

Tags: java, list, methods

I have a class that manages a bunch of list, meaning that the class has 3 ArrayList as private data fields.

I want to be able to print out the necessary information of the objects in those lists into an String array. I want to be able to do it to all three lists, which means I need three methods. The only difference between those methods, is what kind of information I want to take out of the objects, and of course the length of the arrays.

So my question is: Is it better to have **one** method that will identify what I want to print out, or is it better to have three different methods?

example:

```
public String[] method(String type){
    if(type.equals(type1)){
        <print out necessary information from objects>
    }

    <two more methods...>
}
```

Comment: Have 3 different methods so that the code that is needed to execute will only be loaded at the time of call...

Comment: Better is to use OOP priciples. Strategy pattern or method overriding is better approach for that.

Comment: Also, consider using an `enum` instead of `String` for type

Comment: What is enum? What I thought regarding type, is that when you call the method, you write in the parameter what kind list or object you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683):

> Just as classes can benefit from generification, so can methods.
>   Static utility methods are particularly good candidates for
>   generification. All of the “algorithm” methods in Collections (such as
>   binarySearch and sort) have been generified.

So, if it's possible to do one generic method that handles all Lists, that'd be my choice.

I think type detection is not a good idea. One way to avoid it, could be making all the objects of the different lists implement an interface that you could use for printing them.

Then, you could do something like:

```
public String[] method(List<MyPrintableInterface> arg){...
```

Comment: What about my case though? The method first identifies the object type and then runs the method that fits with it. From what I read from the answers, it sounds like bad practice

Answer (score 3):

A method should do exactly one thing. If you can combine them somehow do it. Better practice is a method to represent one procedure and then see if all three methods can be combined in one general method if all three are part of a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 3 classes, `A`, `B` and `C`, wouldn't it be better to provide a common interface, such as `print()` which all classes would implement? You would then just need to implement 1 method.

```
public interface IPrintToScreen {
    public void print();
}

public class A implements IPrintToScreen {
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(...);
        ...
    }
}
...
```

In your code:

```
public void PrintListToScreen(List<IPrintToScreen> listToPrint) {
    for(IPrintToScreen item : listToPrint) {
        item.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My impression you should check: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern or something similar because you asking (if I correctly understand) for some strange problems which should not happen in real life.